# Trouble With Pointers to Pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to write some sort of list in C without creating a global variable for the head of the list and I'm running into some trouble.

I originally had this for my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct Node {
    char *data;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node *init(struct Node *head) {
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    head->data = "abc";
    head->next = NULL;

    return head;
}

struct Node *getHead(struct Node *head) {
    struct Node *retNode = NULL;

    if (head != NULL) {
        retNode = head;
        head = head->next;
    }

    return retNode;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct Node *head;
    head = init(head);
    printf("Head pointer before method:%p\n", head);

    getHead(head);
    printf("Head pointer after method:%p\n", head);
}
```

which generates output:

```
Head pointer before method:0x7fffd36ad260  
Head pointer after method:0x7fffd36ad260
```

I thought this was failing because C is pass by value which led me to believe an identical copy with a different pointer was showing up inside the method. When I checked the pointer to Head inside the method however, I found it was the same as the original head pointer so it seems like the actual pointer is in the method. I don't understand what's going on here so if someone could explain why the head pointer isn't updating even though the same pointer is there that would be great.

I would think it should work since if you have a swap(int *a, int *b) method and the actual pointers are sent from the main then the changes made inside will the method will effect the variables outside as well. After looking online people were saying to use pointers to pointers for this although I can't seem to get that to work.

Attempting to code it as follows:

```
//... same code as before for other methods
struct Node *getHead(struct Node **head)
{
    struct Node *retNode = NULL;

    if (head != NULL)
    {
        retNode = *head;
        *head = *head->next;
    }

    return retNode;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct Node *head;
    head = init(head);
    printf("Head pointer before method:%p\n", head);

    getHead(&head);
    printf("Head pointer after method:%p\n", head);
}
```

Although when trying to compile this I run into the error:

```
pointers.c:50:22: error: ‘*head’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
         *head = *head->next;
```

I'm also at a loss as to why this error is being thrown.

Comment: `*head->next` -->`(*head)->next`

Comment: With the first version the problem is what you thought. With the second version the problem is [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) since `*head->next` is equal to `*(head->next)`.

Comment: And even though you call `init` to assign the `head` node in your `main` function, I suggest you still initialize `head` to `NULL` when you define it. And your `init` function don't need the argument passed, define a new variable locally inside the function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Could you elaborate on why the pointer to head is being displayed as the same value? It would make sense to me if the pointers were different values but since struct Node *head point to the same memory address both inside and outside the method I don't understand why the assignment doesn't work.

Comment: Like you think, arguments are passed by value, i.e. they are copied. The modifications you do to the local variable `head` inside the `getHead` function will not affect the original variable `head` in the `main` function. Therefore you will get the same value in both outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others already pointed out, you'll have to put `*head` into parentheses due to operator precendence.

What I have problems understanding is, why are you overwriting `head` with its successor? Should function `getHead` better be called `removeHead`?

Also note, your `head` parameter in function `init` has no effect, as it is overwritten by the following `malloc`.

I further recommend reading the awesome articel on how Linux kernel implements efficient [lists using struct embedding](https://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/). It's a delight!

Answer (score -2):

Pass a double pointer to `getHead` since you're trying to update `head` in the scope that calls `getHead`.

```
struct Node *getHead(struct Node **head) {
    struct Node *retNode = NULL;

    if (head != NULL && *head != NULL) {
        retNode = *head;
        *head = (*head)->next;
    }

    return retNode;
}
```

The reason `head` is the same value before and after your method in the first attempt is because you never changed the value of `head` in `main`. Your function `getHead` changes its local copy of the pointer `head`. So if you print `head` inside `getHead` in your first attempt, you will see that it points to a different address.