# Operations with pointers in linked lists

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Generally, I know that a pointer stores the memory address of another value located in computer memory, for example:

```
int firstvalue= 5
int * p1;
p1 = &firstvalue;  // p1 = address of firstvalue
```

What happens if we define an operation like the following in a linked list? Does `*current=*list` means that the value pointed to by current equals to the value pointed to by list? And what does it mean if we define `ecur=current`?

```
int function(struct list_t **list){
    struct list_t *ecur=NULL;
    struct list_t *current=*list;
    ecur=current;
}
```

**Update:**
What does it do `*list=remove(*list, param1, param2)`? And why is that?

`remove` is a function that returns a modified list of `list`.

**Update 2:**
Why do we need to define a pointer to pointer in order to modify the list? Is `*list` a pointer to pointer?

Comment: `current` will point to whatever `*list` is pointing to. And `ecur` will point to whatever `cur` is pointing to.

Comment: `ecur=cur` means you didn't type out `current` correctly and so you get a compiler error.

Comment: @StoryTeller, sorry for the typo. Edited.

Comment: `ecur = current;` is just like any other variable assignment. It gives both variables the same value, so they both point to the same place.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the response, and what does it do `*list=*list_2`?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the response, and what does it do `*list=*list_2`?

Comment: It assigns the value that `list_2` points to to the memory that `list` points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `list` is a pointer to a pointer to a struct list_t. If we (just as an example) assume that the struct is placed at address 2000 and that the unnamed pointer is at address 1000 it will look like this:

[image]

Then you have the initialization that adds two new variables. Both as pointer to a struct list_t.

```
struct list_t *ecur=NULL;
struct list_t *current=*list;
```

So the picture now becomes:

[image]

Notice that `current` got the same value as the "some-pointer" in the middle because it is `*list` that was assigned to `current`.

Then you have the assignment:

```
ecur=current;
```

which means that `ecur` gets the same value as `current` and gives the picture:

[image]

> Update: What does it do `*list=remove(*list, param1, param2)` ?

It changes the value of the "some-pointer" in the middle of the picture. This is for instance needed if the `remove` function removes the first element in a linked list.

Comment: Thank you, but how do we know that `struct list_t` is the linked list `list`?

Comment: @Kevin Well, it's just a guess. The name suggest that it is but we can't really know with out seeing the code. Anyway, it make no difference with regard to the pointers in your code. If you have the code for the struct I'm sure you'll see that it has a pointer with the name `next`

Comment: I mean, I have defined the structure of the linked list `struct list_t {int val; struct list_t *next;}; struct list_t *list=NULL;`. How do we know that `some-pointer` points exactly at the first node of the list?

Comment: @Kevin Since you haven't posted all your code, I have to guess again... but I'm pretty sure that you call the function like: `function(&list)` notice the `&`  This also means that `list` inside the function is different from `list` outside the function. In fact the "some-pointer" in the function  is actually the `list` outside the function

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it. Also, shouldn't it be `cur: 1000`, since `*lis` is the argument of the pointer? It is `cur: 2000` because we defined `lis` as a pointer of pointer, so that makes a difference?

Comment: @Kevin The picture is correct. If the code was: `struct list_t *current = list;` (no `*`) **then** `current` would get the value 1000 (like `list`) **but** the code is `struct list_t *current = *list;` (with *) so `current` get the value that `list` points to! And that is 2000.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of the problem in a wrong way. Now it's more clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we need to define a pointer to pointer in order to modify the list? Is *list a pointer to pointer?

Remember that C passes all function arguments by value - the formal argument in the function definition is a different object in memory from the actual argument in the function call.  For example:

```
void swap( int a, int b )
{
  int tmp = a;
  a = b;
  b = tmp;
}

void foo( void )
{
  int x = 1;
  int y = 2;

  swap( x, y );
}
```

`a` is a different object in memory than `x`, and `b` is a different object in memory than `y`, so swapping `a` and `b` has no effect on `x` and `y`.  In order to swap the values of `x` and `y`, you must pass *pointers* to them:

```
void swap( int *a, int *b )
{
  int tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
}

void foo( void )
{
  int x = 1;
  int y = 2;

  swap( &x, &y );
}
```

The *expression* `*a` is the same as `x`, so writing to `*a` is the same as writing to `x`.  Same for `*b` and `y`.

So, in order for a function to write to a parameter, you must pass a *pointer* to that parameter:

```
void foo ( T *arg )
{
  *arg = new_value(); // writes a new value to the thing arg points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  T var;
  foo( &var );        // write a new value to var
}
```

This is true for *any non-array type `T`*.  Let's replace `T` with a pointer type `P *`:

```
void foo( P **arg )
{
  *arg = new_value(); // write a new *pointer* value to the thing arg points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  P *var;
  foo( &var );        // write a new pointer value to var
}
```

The semantics are exactly the same - all that's changed is the type.

If a function has the potential to modify a `list *` object (say pointing it at a new list head), then you must pass a pointer to that `list *` object:

```
void add_node( struct list_t **list, struct list_t *node )
{
  if ( !*list || (node->value < (*list)->value) ) // make node new head of list
    *list = node;
  else
    // add node somewhere else in the list
}

int main( void )
{
  struct list_t *list = NULL;
  ...
  struct list_t *node = newNode( value );
  add_node( &list, node );
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 0):

```
TYPE *p = ptype /*variable of type: TYPE * */;
```

is not an *assignment*. It's an **initialization**, which for an `auto`-matic (=on-the-stack) p can be rewritten as:

```
TYPE *p;
p = ptype;
```

(not `TYPE *p; *p=ptype; /*would be a type error*/`)

In terms of your example:

```
struct list_t *current=*list;
```

sets where `current` will point to (the same place as what `*list` points to (`*list` is also a pointer because `list` is a doubly-indirect pointer)) without doing anything whatsoever with what current will point at (`*current`) after the initialization.

All of this is just conceptual, though. Your function doesn't have any externally visible effects so an optimizing compiler should completely delete its body.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and what does it do `*list=*list_2`?

Comment: @Kevin - what is `list_2`?  Where does it fit in the code you've posted so far?

Comment: @JohnBode For clarification, `list_2` is the return list from a function that modifies `list`. I haven't added it because I didn't want to lose the focus of the problem.

Comment: @Kevin - the problem is you're asking us about code that isn't in the body of your question (especially the update asking about `remove`).  We're not psychic, and the best we can do is guess based on the naming conventions.  There are operations common to list management, but without seeing the actual code you're asking about, we can't tell you why it does what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar knot in my head with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340755/trouble-with-pointers-to-pointers-in-c/). I'd like to rearrange your function a bit, so it's easier to understand what's going on:

```
int function(struct list_t **list)
{
    struct list_t *current = *list;
    struct list_t *ecur    = current;
}
```

If we call this function with an element `foo` we essentially get this:

```
struct list_t foo      = { .data = "foo" };
struct list_t *bar     = &foo;
struct list_t **list   = &bar;
struct list_t *current = *list;
struct list_t *ecur    = current;
```

We have five declarations and five assignments. For better readability, I'll write everything down without declarations:

```
foo     = { .data = "foo" };
bar     = &foo;
list    = &bar;
current = *list;
ecur    = current;
```

Now, let's walk through it:

1. `foo` is a struct. It contains the above data-field.
2. `bar` is a pointer to struct. It contains the address of `foo`
3. `list` is a pointer to a pointer to struct. It contains the address of `bar`
4. `current` is a pointer to struct. It contains the contents of the contents of `list`, which is the address of `foo`
5. `ecur` is a pointer to struct. It's identical to `current` and contains the address `bar`

In the end we can simplify the whole example to this:

```
struct list_t foo   = { .data = "foo" };
struct list_t *ecur = &foo;
```

What does it all mean?

- `list`: Because `list` is a pointer to a pointer you are able to modify `bar` to point to something completely different, by de-referencing it (`*list = ...`)
- `current`/`ecur`: that's what `bar` originally pointed too. By de-referencing you could change the data-field itself (`(*ecur).data = "banana"` or better `ecur->data`)

I hope I could clarify things and didn't make it worse ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we need to define a pointer to pointer in order to modify the
>   list?

Let me add a complete program, albeit short, to illustrate it better.  It defines a simply linked list and builds it while keeping it ordered.  Yes, I know it would be easier to simply call `qsort()`, but I want to demonstrate how adding one level of indirection —the pointer to pointer— allows to insert elements smoothly, without testing for special cases.

```c
// C pointer exercise: sort arguments
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list
{
    char *arg;
    struct list *next;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // pointer to base, running pointer and pointer to pointer
    struct list *base = NULL, *p, **pp;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        struct list *new_entry = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        if (new_entry)
        {
            new_entry->arg = argv[i];

            // find where to insert new entry
            for (pp = &base; *pp; pp = &(*pp)->next)
                if (strcasecmp(new_entry->arg, (*pp)->arg) < 0)
                    break;

            // insertion in a simply linked list
            new_entry->next = *pp;
            *pp = new_entry;
        }
    }

    // display and cleanup
    for (p = base; p;)
    {
        struct list * tmp = p->next;
        puts(p->arg);
        free(p);
        p = tmp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```